# How do I fast foward branches without switching to them?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I currently am on my `master` branch, and my stage is dirty. I don't want to commit and I already have too many stashes to stash my changes (or am I too lazy ?).

I would like to move fast foward some branches **without switching to them** (remember, my stage is dirty).

How could I fastfoward `optim` to `mobile` ? or `optim` to `master` (my current branch) ?

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUPeq.png

Comment: If you name your stashes `git stash save <"message">` you shouldn't have the issue of too many stashes being a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: a branch name is merely a pointer to a (single) commit.  The thing we tend to think of as "the branch"—the whole chain of commits—is found by working from each commit backwards to its parent(s).  The parents are recorded only in the commits themselves, not in any branch names.  It may help to think of branch names as sticky-notes that are pasted on to some particular commit.  I can't draw that in text so I draw it below as an arrow (`<--`) instead.

Translating your image to text, rotating it, making an assumption or two, and truncating a bit to fit nicely in this answer, you're showing:

```
                                        o...
                                       /
--o--M--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o    <-- mobile
    /
---o                                       <-- optim, origin/optim
```

(Here "newer" stuff is towards the right, instead of above, and the text of the various commit messages is omitted.)

A "fast forward" occurs when:<sup>1</sup>

- you are "on a branch", i.e., `HEAD` is a symbolic reference to a branch name
- you ask git to merge with another commit (by name or SHA1 ID; usually by branch-name)
- and, the "merge with" commit is "straight ahead" of where the branch is now, i.e., it's possible to simply slide the branch name along some set of "descendent" links to get there.  (More precisely, the `HEAD` commit is an ancestor of the "to-be-merged" commit.)

Since `optim` points to a commit whose single descendent is the merge commit `M`, and that commit has one descendent for each little `o` to the right, git can slide the branch name `optim` forward along that chain of commits.

Hence:

```
$ git checkout optim; git merge mobile
```

would slide the label up-and-right to M, then further right to where `mobile` points, giving:

```
                                        o...
                                       /
--o--M--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o    <-- mobile, optim
    /
---o                                       <-- origin/optim
```

If you want to do that "manually", without doing anything else and without even being "on" that branch, you can just tell git "please re-point the branch name `optim` to target the same commit as the name `mobile`:

```
$ git branch -f optim mobile
```

The `-f` (or `--force`) flag says to go ahead and change an existing label's target-commit, rather than erroring out.

This command does not check that the operation is a fast-forward.  (Of course plain `git merge` only checks for that to decide whether to do a fast-forward merge, or a "real" merge.  However, you can ask `git merge` to do `--ff-only`, i.e., error out if the operation is *not* a fast-forward.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Fetch and push also apply the same kind of "fast forward" notion, so this is "when" but not "only when".

Comment: Thank you, I am really using this on a regular basis (at least weekly) `git branch -f late_branch newest_branch`

Comment: @gasp: check out the other answer and the `ff` alias in its last comment, too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git push . mobile:optim` (yes, that's a dot) to fast-forward `optim` to `mobile`.

Comment: The `push` updates the branch-name stored on the remote (and then moves `origin/optim`, the local copy of "where I last found that the remote has `optim` set"); this is not the same thing.  (Might still be what the OP wants in the end, though.)

Comment: D'oh, I'm wrong, the `.` means that the remote *is* the local, so this works fine and uses the "push" machinery to check that the change is a fast-forward.

Comment: ...and an alias `ff` that looks like this: `!f() { git push . $1@{u}:$1; }; f` is very handy.

Comment: @StefanNäwe: when I try that alias, it gives me an error `fatal: No upstream configured for branch 'test'` (test is the branch I'm trying to fast forward).  Is there a way to configure a "local" upstream just for this (independent of any upstream configured for any remote repo?)

Comment: @Chris Dodd: What do you mean by "local upstream" ?

Comment: @StefanNäwe: the local branch point that I want to fast-forward to (usually 'master' or 'trunk')