# Is there any direct git command to push changes to another branch

Tags: git, github

This is my `"git show feature/2.8.0"`

```
$ git show feature/2.8.0 
commit 47c58e2f8fa6064779e9b059587db388dc233265
Author: laxmikantG <laxmikant@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 3 09:43:15 2014 +0530

    Bug #68281

diff --git a/inheritance_tax/src/lib/form/ihtx_f_01_00_00_00_00_h240401_init.erl b/inheritance_tax/src/lib/form/ihtx_f_01_00_00_00_00_h240401_init.erl
index c3573cd..047c7df 100644
--- a/inheritance_tax/src/lib/form/ihtx_f_01_00_00_00_00_h240401_init.erl
+++ b/inheritance_tax/src/lib/form/ihtx_f_01_00_00_00_00_h240401_init.erl
@@ -24,8 +24,8 @@ process(AncestorId) ->
                        %%'F_02_0055', data_util:to_timestamp_list(form_util:create_list(date_of_birth, Heirs)),
             'F_02_0055', form_util:create_list(date_of_birth, Heirs),
                        'F_02_0056', form_util:create_list(age, Heirs),
-                       'F_02_0057', form_util:create_list(zip_code, Heirs),
-                       'F_02_0058', form_util:create_list(address, Heirs),
+                       'F_02_0057', form_util:create_list(address, Heirs),
+                       'F_02_0058', form_util:create_list(zip_code, Heirs),
                        'F_02_0059', form_util:create_list(phone_number, Heirs),
                        'F_02_0060', form_util:create_list(relationship, Heirs),
                        'F_02_0061', form_util:create_list(occupation, Heirs),
```

I have committed my changes by mistake to `feature/2.8.0`. but not pushed yet. I have to commit and push it to "develop" branch.

Thanks

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19715029/720999)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cherry-pick the commit to the desired branch:

```
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick feature/2.8.0
```

Then roll-back the branch:

```
git checkout feature/2.8.0
git reset --hard HEAD^
```